# Ruby on Rails- Adding Comments to a Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a website using ruby on rails which allow users to submit a recipe. I have called it Recipeazy. I am not sure how I can allow users to add comments (which the user who submitted a comment can edit, and delete the comment). 
This is a link to my code: https://ide.c9.io/kingsong/recipeazy
And I'm not sure if this will work for me:https://thinkster.io/tutorials/rails-json-api/adding-comments-to-articles

If I am not clear, please tell me if there is any code I should post.

Thanks.

Comment: Both links are behind a login or paywall, so aren't providing much context to provide an answer. The answer provided by user Matt D below is a good starting point but without code samples, and knowing what problems you're having (views, model, controller, etc.) the scope of this question could be quite large

Answer (score 2):

1. Neither of the two links you provided work.
2. What you are trying to accomplish is very easy!

This is a *simple* commenting setup. This consists of a `Recipe` model, `Comment` model, and `User` model. All these models will be related to each other.

**models/recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

**models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Like I said, this is a simple commenting setup. This does not address authorization, or nested comments.